# Generic List<T> as parameter on method

Tags: c#, generics, c#-3.0

How can I use a `List<T>` as a parameter on a method, I try this syntax :

```
void Export(List<T> data, params string[] parameters){

}
```

I got compilation error:

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 185, accepted):

To take a generic `List<T>` vs a bound `List<int>` you need to make the method generic as well.  This is done by adding a generic parameter to the method much in the way you add it to a type.

Try the following

```
void Export<T>(List<T> data, params string[] parameters) {
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 24):

You need to make the method generic as well:

```
void Export<T>(List<T> data, params string[] parameters){

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Also found out, that one can use multiple Ts

Comment: How to return field by name from generic list? Let's say listGeneric[0].fieldName.

Comment: There are a number of ways to approach that, @FrenkyB. I would suggest you post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 7):

```
public static  List<T> pesquisa_lista<T>(string campo, string valor, List<T> lista)  
{
   return new List<T>();
}
```