# How to make a method generic when "type 'T' must be a reference type"?

Tags: c#, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Why do I get “error: … must be a reference type” in my C# generic method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1992443/why-do-i-get-error-must-be-a-reference-type-in-my-c-generic-method)

I have 2 Repository methods that are almost identical:

```
public IList<Fund> GetFundsByName(int pageSize, string searchExpression)
{
    return _session.CreateCriteria<Fund>()
        .AddNameSearchCriteria<Fund>(searchExpression)
        .AddOrder<Fund>(f => f.Name, Order.Asc)
        .SetMaxResults(pageSize).List<Fund>();
}

public IList<Company> GetCompaniesByName(int pageSize, string searchExpression)
{
    return _session.CreateCriteria<Company>()
        .AddNameSearchCriteria<Company>(searchExpression)
        .AddOrder<Company>(f => f.Name, Order.Asc)
        .SetMaxResults(pageSize).List<Company>();
}
```

The only difference is that the first one's `_session.CreateCriteria` is of type `Fund` and the second one is `company`

I was hoping that I could make this generic by changing the method definition to:

```
public IList<T> GetEntitiesByName<T>(int pageSize, string searchExpression)
    where T : ISearchableEntity
{
    return _session.CreateCriteria<T>()
        .AddNameSearchCriteria<T>(searchExpression)
        .AddOrder<T>(f => f.Name, Order.Asc)
        .SetMaxResults(pageSize).List<T>();
}
```

where ISearchableEntity is defined as:

```
public interface ISearchableEntity
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

but unfortunately NHibernate doesn't like this and gives me the error:

`The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'NHibernate.ISession.CreateCriteria<T>()'`

Is it possible for me to make this generic some other way?

Comment: Are `Fund` and `Company` Classes?

Comment: @AllenG, yes, Fund & Company are classes

Comment: Could also possibly look at the CreateCriteria function sourcecode and see how they constrain it to a reference type and perhaps you could employ the same method to constrain your generic type to a reference type.

Comment: @AAronLS, `CreateCriteria` is defined in some NHibernate assemby or another, so I don't have access to the source

Comment: NHibernate is open source, here is the file for CreateCriteria which shows they use `where T : class;`: http://nhibernate.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhibernate/trunk/nhibernate/src/NHibernate/ISession.cs?revision=4868&view=markup

Comment: I love that earned "Notable Question" for this and it's been "closed as exact duplicate" for close to 2 years :-/

Comment: As is frequently the case, it's only obvious these are the same question once you understand the answer. I call this multiple search vectors - different paths of enquiry leading to the same piece of understanding. The rule Nazis don't seem to think it's useful to support multiple search vectors.

Answer (score 212, accepted):

You could try adding the constraint `class`:

```
where T : class, ISearchableEntity
```

Comment: At first I assumed this only worked if T had to be a Class, but after looking at the page linked in theburningmonk's answer I found out that despite the name of this constraint, "this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type." So use `where T : class` even if you need T to be an interface, as was my case.

Comment: This also works for struct

Answer (score 29):

Here's the full list of constraints you can use on T

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: NOTE:  If one is calling a method and gets this error, Int32? (e.g.) will not work as a reference type, but the array Int32?[] will work as such!