# Have a dynamic parameter for a List in Function

Tags: c#, list, parameters

I have a SOAP APi which needs an XML string created to send as the request.
There are a number of different XML strings required.

eg. the Customer and Item strings are quite different and there is no WDSL ability on this old software.

I have a function to check which API enpoint is being called, then get the action, uRL and envelope (XML) from predefined functions.

```
private static (string URL, string action, string envelope) getTaskDetails(string task, 
List<Object> envelopeList)
        {
            string _action = "";
            string _URL = "";
            string _envelope = "";


            switch (task)
            {
                case "getCustomerDetails":
                    _action = minfosDetails.minfosCustomerAction;
                    _URL = minfosDetails.minfosCustomerURL;
                    _envelope = getCustomerDetails(envelopeList);
                    break;

                default:
                    
                    break;

            }

            return (_URL, _action, _envelope);
        }
```

The aobve is the (not working) code.

What I want is the List (which I know is wrong) to accept any LIST thrown at it.

eg. I can send the customerList to it, or the ItemList or the staffList etc.
Then when i run the switch, it will take the List and throw it into the subfunction to get the envolope created.

EDIT: Question answered, my working code below:
Using

```
getTaskDetails<T>(string task, List<T> envelopeList)
```

To call the next function I used:

```
_envelope = getCustomerDetails(envelopeList.Cast<ACustomer>());
```

Comment: What is the signature of `getCustomerDetails`?

Comment: @Dialecticus 
public static string getCustomerDetails(List<ACustomer> customerList)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using generics so the method is going to change like this

```
private static (string URL, string action, string envelope) getTaskDetails<T>(List<T> envelopeList)
```

then you can check for what T Type is being passed instead of using your parameter `string task`

Comment: Thanks for the response:  I did try that, but this is what I got:
The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I Edited the answer, you need to add <T> after the method name also

Comment: You can also see this post: [Generic List<T> as parameter on method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633690/generic-listt-as-parameter-on-method)

Comment: THanks, I've updated my working code below in an edit

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to simply cast `List<object>` to `List<ACustomer>`. You can create a new list instead.

```
_envelope = getCustomerDetails(envelopeList.Cast<ACustomer>().ToList());
```

OR, you could change the signature of `getCustomerDetails` to accept `IEnumerable` instead of `List`:

```
public static string getCustomerDetails(IEnumerable<ACustomer> customerList)
```

And then the `.ToList()` part is not needed, and no new list is created:

```
_envelope = getCustomerDetails(envelopeList.Cast<ACustomer>());
```

To use `Cast` extension method you have to be `using System.Linq;`

Comment: Great thanks, I'lll give it a try now